# How to parse response after creating card using Trello API

Tags: api, jsonp, response, trello

I'm playing around with the [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/index.html) and I'm slowly getting the hang of it. I'm stuck on one piece where I manage to create a new card inside a speicifc list, but I'd like to parse the response I get from the "createCard" call e.g. to get the ID of the new card.

Here is my Trello create card post:

```
Trello.post("cards", { name: "Card Created from MVC", desc: "This is the description of the card.", idList: "??????????" }).done(onCardCreated());
```

I've omitted the real `idList` value for secutiry reasons.

I can see the card instantly on my Trello board. The response I get from this call starts like this:

```
jQuery1510518084118841216_1327764237952({"id":"????","name":"Card Created from MVC","desc":........)
```

I was expecting to see the JSON returned liked this:

```
{"id":"????","name":"Card Created from MVC","desc":....}
```

But in this case, the JSON is wrapped around in this `jQuery1510518084118841216_1327764237952` thing.

Can some tell me what the jQuery thing is for, and how do I get to the JSON data inside of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the request is going to another domain (i.e. api.trello.com), the [client-side library](https://api.trello.com/1/client.coffee) is using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

The library is using [jQuery's AJAX calls](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (with the `jsonp` dataType), which is why the JSONP callback has a "jQuery" name.

Although the actual response you see includes the JSONP callback, the response from the library that is given to the success callback should just include the JSON.

I would expect that something like this should work:

```
Trello 
.post("cards", { name: "Foo", desc: "Bar", idList:"..."}) 
.done(function(card) { alert(card.id) })
```